# How to apply focused state to same element again when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For my Form input, I would like to re-do the animation of my focused state for an input like:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control">
```

You can see it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/esg1dzy0/

With that said, I can't get it to do so with this:

```
  $(document.activeElement).click(function(){
    this.focus();
  });
```

Is this possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just a shot in the dark, but try blurring first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to blur the element first.

Before you do that, you need to make sure this is not the first click on the element.

Also, your original selector will only select the element that is active at the time that your snippet runs.

Finally, use mousedown to avoid flickering.

```
$('.form-control').mousedown(function(){
    if(!$(this).is(':focus')) return;
    $(this).blur().focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you:

```
$('.form-control').on('click', function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var duration = 300;
  var enableAgain = function(){
    $this.blur().focus();
  };

  setTimeout(enableAgain, duration);
});
```

This trigger the the `blur()` and `focus()` event again after `300 milliseconds` (in the best of the case), which is the same as `transition-duration` you maybe want a greater value like `350`.

BTW I have editt your https://jsfiddle.net/esg1dzy0/ file.